# how to extract decision rules of GradientBosstingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to extract and visualize the decision rules of a scikit-learn `GradientBoostingClassifier`. If it were just one DecisionTreeClassifier I'd use `tree.export_graphviz`, but `GradientBoostingClassifier` is an ensemble of trees. I don't know how I'd use `export_graphviz` on them.

If anyone knows of a way to do so, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has solved the problem.
"You can use clf.estimators_ to retrieve the DecisionTreeRegressor objects corresponding to each boosting stage and call export_graphviz to generate the tree visualization..
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html"